# How to play multiple consecutive sound files with javaFX?

Tags: java, audio, javafx, media-player

I want to play 5 sound files one after the other using javaFX. I'm struggling to play more than two in a row. This code only plays the first two sound files, then doesn't play the third one. I want to be able to play up to 5 sound files, but not having a limit would be ideal. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!
I'm trying to make a talking clock that tells you the time, and I'm stuck on the part where you get it to talk.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MediaFX extends Application{


    MediaPlayer mediaplayer; 

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
        Media hello = new Media("file:///C:/Users/Good/Desktop/TimeFiles/one.wav");
        Media meow = new Media("file:///C:/Users/Good/Desktop/TimeFiles/oh.wav");
        Media neww = new Media("file:///C:/Users/Good/Desktop/TimeFiles/six.wav");

        mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer(hello);
        mediaplayer.play();
        mediaplayer.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                mediaplayer.stop();
                mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer(meow);
                mediaplayer.setAutoPlay(false);
                mediaplayer.play();
            }
        });
        mediaplayer.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                mediaplayer.stop();
                mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer(neww);
                mediaplayer.setAutoPlay(false);
                mediaplayer.play();
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to find a way to create loop of certain actions in order to be able to achieve what you want. You need to :

1. Find if there is still available songs to be played
2. Create a new Instance of MediaPlayer and set the next song
3. Set to check again for new song after the end of the current one.
4. Goto to Number 1

A nice way of doing that is by recursive calls of a init functions like below :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MediaFX extends Application {

    MediaPlayer mediaplayer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Media hello = new Media(this.getClass().getResource("one.wav").toExternalForm());
        Media meow = new Media(this.getClass().getResource("two.wav").toExternalForm());
        Media neww = new Media(this.getClass().getResource("three.wav").toExternalForm());

        ObservableList<Media> mediaList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        mediaList.addAll(hello, meow, neww);

        playMediaTracks(mediaList);

        VBox root = new VBox();

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root,300,300));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void playMediaTracks(ObservableList<Media> mediaList) {
        if (mediaList.size() == 0)
            return;

        MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer(mediaList.remove(0));
        mediaplayer.play();

        mediaplayer.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                playMediaTracks(mediaList);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Won't this lead to memory issues say you kept repeating the same songs? Don't you need to dispose the MediaPlayer once you are finished with it?